# What does "Jewish nose" imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, expressions, phrases, idioms-in-context

In the following link of the [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVAFWBx83RY) video at 1:10, the bride says: "He is an Irishman with a Jewish nose." What does "Jewish nose" imply to make people laugh out loud in the video? Can someone help with that? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't imply anything just that the groom's nose is generally recognised as not being canonically beautiful. If she had said he had a boxer's nose people would have laughed the same.

Comment: Did you search for "Jewish nose"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about culture, not a question about language. I admit that it's difficult to have one without the other, but there is a difference between "what does the phrase 'Jewish Nose' mean?" (can have a single, objective answer) and "why is the phrase 'Jewish Nose' funny?" (terrifying if anyone believes it can have a single, objective answer). Credit due to the existing answers, though, that took a good stab at it.

Answer (score 1):

> Jewish nose or Jew's nose is a usually over-exaggerated ethnic stereotype that refers to a hooked nose with a convex nasal bridge and a downward turn of the tip of the nose. — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_nose)

Why is this funny to some though? Jokes are often made out of racist stereotypes and, of course, decent people avoid them. You can look at [“Jewish Nose” Jokes Aren’t Funny. In Fact, They’re Dangerous](https://www.thej.ca/2021/10/06/jewish-nose-jokes-arent-funny-in-fact-theyre-dangerous/) for Jewish-nose jokes, and why they are dangerous (not related but the only thing I could find online about this).

Or, the bridegroom presumably isn't Jewish, and just happens to have a rather hooked nose.

Comment: Yes. But why? Why do people laugh out loud about that over-exaggerated stereotype?

Comment: @questionguy This is a hard question to answer, I tried my best :( (I edited my answer)

Comment: Presumably the bridegroom isn't Jewish, he just happens to have a rather hooked nose.

Comment: @DialFrost Thank you. Guess I need to ask those Irishmen for the reason of laughing.

Comment: Jokes are often made out of racist stereotypes and, of course, decent people avoid them.

Comment: @questionguy - bad or stupid people laugh at racist jokes.

Comment: People don't just laugh at jokes, they can laugh when something doesn't fit their expectations. That's not a question about English though.

Comment: If you're going to copy from an outside source, that's fine but you absolutely positively have to make sure it's [clear that the words aren't your own and where they came from](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) (as I have done).

Answer (score 0):

This is a controversial subject - some people instantly feel that the term 'a Jewish nose' is offensive and racist. Whether it is or is not offensive is entirely opinion-based.

It is often said that every joke has a *subject* and a *target*, and that these two can be very different. In wedding speeches, it is very common for the groom to be the target of jokes (normally from the best man, and not usually from the bride, but that is what makes this video unique). I perceive that people are laughing so hard because she has made fun of the groom's nose, which is perhaps large or prominent. Of course, to do this by comparing it to a racial stereotype is where it could become offensive to some.

Context is everything. We don't know if perhaps the Irish groom has some Jewish heritage. Mentioning physical or personality characteristics of a race is not inherently racist - most observational comedy is based on stereotypes, and many comedians refer to their own heritage for humour. Of course, joking about the race of *another* is more likely to be perceived as racist, especially when it comes to races or ethnic groups that have historically experienced persecution or suffering at the hands of others. Jewish persons have sometimes been portrayed in fiction with grotesquely exaggerated physical characteristics. This kind of portrayal, to engender negative feelings towards them, is obviously offensive, but there is no reason to assume that a person referring to 'a Jewish nose' means this kind of portrayal.

You'll notice that she frequently mentions her own Chinese heritage for humour, and also makes jokes to the mainly Irish audience about the Irish being drunk, which they laugh equally hard at. Self-deprecating humour is very much part of *some* English-speaking cultures, and it is my experience that these cultures are less sensitive to jokes about others, rightly or wrongly.

Overall, I feel confident in saying that the joke is funny to the audience primarily because they are laughing at their friend/relative, the groom. I don't think they are laughing solely at a racial stereotype. The fact that the bride is Chinese and the event is clearly a celebration of the union between two different cultures sets a scene where this kind of joke is least likely to be perceived as offensive... that is until they put it on the internet to be viewed by the entire world, out of context. That said, I looked at some of her other YouTube content and she seems to have done some work as a stand-up comedian and racial stereotypes seem to figure quite heavily in her material. Again, being a Chinese girl in an English speaking country may give her a certain freedom of speech in the eyes of her audience.

Answer (score 0):

Humor is about expectations. *No one expects the juxtaposition of Irish and Jewish like that.* So while in some contexts this might be racist, it isn't racist here. Comedians can say things others can't, really.

Obviously, the Nazis exploited this in their imagery on Jews. So nasty.

But, in the streaming sitcom the Marvelous Mrs. Maisel which is all about a Jewish comedian woman from an upper-class Jewish family, someone says something about a Jewish nose and they are all Jewish. So, it's one of those things.

Here is a college course on these issues of stereotypical representations:

*The Five Rachels: Jewish Women in Contemporary American Culture*
CJST 252
Fall 2021   Section: 01
Crosslisting: RELI 252

> The course will focus on five iconic contemporary female TV
> characters, actors, and creators; American, Jewish, and
> incidentally--or not--sharing the same name: Rachel. Rachel Green
> ("Friends"), Rachel Berry ("Glee"), Rachel Menken ("Mad Men"), and
> Rebecca Bunch ("Crazy Ex-Girlfriend"), played by Rachel Bloom, and
> Midge Maisel ("The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel"), played by Rachel
> Brosnahan. These five complement each other and offer us a panoramic
> view of the American Jewish female experience: discrimination,
> inclusion, the generational gap, and their relationship with Israel.
> **In addition, they allow us to explore the three most common
> stereotypes associated with the Jewish woman: the Jewish nose, the
> Jewish mother, and the Jewish American princess**. We will discuss the
> conflicts and the societal shifts these characters embody, and how
> they define themselves, their Jewishness, their femininity, their
> unique surroundings, and place in history.

[course on the American Jewish female experience](https://owaprod-pub.wesleyan.edu/reg/!wesmaps_page.html?stuid=&crse=016074&term=1219)

Here is the description of another sitcom series that deals with this:

> 3. In the episode “Born This Way,” Rachel considers getting rhinoplasty after feeling insecure about her “Jewish nose.” Her
>    friends try to help her accept her nose, with Kurt Hummel (played by
>    Chris Colfer) pointing out that one of her Jewish idols, Barbra
>    Streisand, publicly refused to get a nose job. In the end, Rachel
>    decides to pass on the plastic surgery.

[description of sitcom with](https://owaprod-pub.wesleyan.edu/reg/!wesmaps_page.html?stuid=&crse=016074&term=1219)

So basically, even Jewish girls/women have this "thing" with a Jewish nose. It's all about who says it and in what context. A blanket "prohibition" on it misses the point.

This is *similar to* but not the same as exactly, the N-word. Rappers use it, gangbangers use it, some AAVE speakers use it but a white person should never use it.